# Trying to use Deque to limit DataFrame of incoming data... suggestions?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, quantitative-finance

I've imported deque from collections to limit the size of my data frame. When new data is entered, the older ones should be progressively deleted over time.

**Big Picture:**
Im creating a Data Frame of historical values of the previous 26 days from time "whatever day it is..."

**Confusion:**
I think my data each minute comes in a series format, which then I attempted to restrict the maxlen using deque. Then I tried implementing the data into an data frame. However I just get NaN values.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import deque

def initialize(context):
    context.stocks = (symbol('AAPL'))

def before_trading_start(context, data):
    data = data.history(context.stocks, 'close', 20, '1m').dropna()
    length = 5
    d = deque(maxlen = length)
    data = d.append(data)
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2016-04-03 00:00:00', freq='S', periods=length)
    columns = ['price']
    df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns, data=data)

    print df
```

How can I get this to work?

Mike

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation of your code?

Comment: What is `data` in your code, I mean the input to the function? It would be very helpful to have an example input, wrong output and desired output. in other words a [mcve]

Comment: [`d.append(data)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.append) will just append *the object the name data points to* at the end of the deque. Did you mean to use [`deque.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque.extend)? Or even better, just `data = deque(data, maxlen=length)`. Using a deque here though seems like an XY problem. I'm sure `DataFrame`s provide ways to limit to desired size.

Comment: did you find a solution for it? I am also looking for the answer for the same?

Comment: @shalini-garg I see you have raised a bounty for this. But this question itself lacks details about the data being used with inputs. Unless the inputs are shown this would become a difficult problem to solve. If you have a similar problem, then maybe raise a separate question with valid input/output examples?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly the question, you want to keep all the values of the last twenty six last days. Does the following function is enough for you?

```py
def select_values_of_the_last_twenty_six_days(old_data, new_data):
    length = 5
    twenty_six_day_before = (
        pd.Timestamp.now(tz='Europe/Paris').round('D')
        - pd.to_timedelta(26, 'D')
    )
    return (
        pd.concat([old_data, new_data])
        .loc[lambda x: x.index > twenty_six_day_before, :]
        .iloc[-length:, :]
    )
```

If the dates are not in the index:

```py
def select_values_of_the_last_twenty_six_days(old_data, new_data):
    length = 5
    twenty_six_day_before = (
        pd.Timestamp.now(tz='Europe/Paris').round('D')
        - pd.to_timedelta(26, 'D')
    )
    return (
        pd.concat([old_data, new_data])
        # the following line is changed for values in a specific column
        .loc[lambda x: x['column_with_date'] > twenty_six_day_before, :]
        .iloc[-length:, :]
    )
```

Don't forget to change the hard coded timezone if you are not in France. :-)

Comment: Thanks for answer but it still don't have dataframe which automatically truncate data like data in dequeu

Comment: I edit the code with a final `iloc` allowing you to select the last 5 elements. Is this what you want? If there are less than 5 rows, they will be all selected.

Comment: But it wouldn't truncate data like dequeue does. This is just querying option

Comment: Can you share some example of your data?  Without it, it's hard to understand the work to do.